# Can not login in my site with mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I need some help here.  I have coded some kind of site with "login" system and trying to prevent SQL injections. Everything works just perfect without that escape string thingy. When I add in mysql_real_escape_string() I can not log in my site anymore and its annoying.

I got no ideas what should be wrong, had tried to google the problem but didn't find anything. So I have got a form, that sends information about user through $_POST['user'] and $_POST['pass'] into check.php. In check.php I have got code to check if user and pass equals with user and pass in MySQL DB.

```
<?php
include ('mysql.php'); // includes mysql connection
    if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'"));

    if(($user == $row[1]) and ($pass == $row[2])) {
        setcookie("user",$user,time() + 3600,"/");
        header('location: secret.php'); 
    } else {
        header('location: index.php');
    };
};
```

Usernames and passwords contain only letters and numbers, and I know that I'm typing username and password correctly.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: First off, you make a lot of errors in general with your closing of if sentences. Second, you should use prepared statements as they are made to protect against SQL Injection. And while in developement, NEVER suppress errors, set the settings provided by @Fred-ii-

Comment: *"Can not login in my site with mysql_real_escape_string"* - Question is, can you login without it?

Comment: Yes I can log in without it. Will check for php errors, thanks.

Comment: There's your answer then ;-) and you're welcome.

Comment: Did any of the answers below work then?

Comment: I think Mathieu's answer helped cause I can log in while i'm on localhost. Will see tommorow will it work and got to re-check whole my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If usernames and passwords only contains alpha-numerics character, try to use
[ctype_alnum ( string $text )](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ctype-alnum.php) so you just verify if $user and $pass are only alpha-numerics characters. If they are (if its returning true), you then dont need to sanitize them.

By the way, you should now use
mysqli_real_escape_string  instead of mysql_real_escape_string !
mysql_* functions are deprecated.

I hope it'll help

Have a look on this similar question, that have been solved:
http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/68338-solved-cant-login-using-mysql-real-escape-string/

Edit: Also,  Fred -ii-'s comment provided you a good method to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use the `mysql_real_escape_string` on values that are going to be included in SQL text.

e.g.

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($user) . "'";

    ... mysql_query($sql) ...
```

Later in your code you are comparing the contents of `$user` to something else. If `$user` contains a return value from `mysql_real_escape_string`, then what you are comparing it should *also* be an equivalently "escaped" value.

As an example, consider:

```
$bar = mysql_real_escape_string($foo);
if ( $bar == $foo ) {
```

Depending on the value of `$foo`, the string stored in `$bar` may not be equal.

The value returned from `mysql_real_escape_string` is "escaped" so it can be included in SQL text.

---

**Additional Notes:**

Storing passwords in plain text is a really bad idea.

Not checking for errors returned from `mysql_query` is a bad idea.

Using deprecated `mysql` interface when two suitable replacements (`mysqli` and `PDO`) are available is a bad idea. Especially when both of the replacements support **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.

Using `*` in the SELECT list, and then referencing the columns returned by position of the columns in the resultset is also a bad idea. It's best practice to list the specific columns you want to return.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas, will use those stuff you posted. be the way, $user value is included in my mysql query to select the user from table.

Comment: @Pie: Yes, `$user` is being included in the SQL text. And it should be made "safe" for inclusion using the `mysql_real_escape_string`.  **But**  you are *also* referencing `$user` in a later comparison, and as argument to set_cookie.